# eclipse: how to enable JavaScript validation on an existing Android project

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, html, validation

I'm developing a web app for Android. I've set up a regular Android eclipse project, with all web files inside assets/www. I'd like to see JavaScript and JSHint warnings in the problems tab as well.

JavaScript Development Tools is installed. I can correctly see the syntax coloring, but if I type something incorrect in a js file I can't see any problem when building.

Is it possible to manually add a new builder for this project? Any other way to enable at least JSHint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plug-in for jshint support in Eclipse: [jshint-eclipse](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/958). The current jshint version (1.1.0) has a severe [performance issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/958) that slow down Eclipse if you have a lot of JS files to check. The bug is already fixed and the fix will be included in the next version.

Comment: I have that plugin installed too. Never noticed slowdowns since I usually disable the "build automatically" option. But then again, in this eclipse install, only android and Java builders are run. Neither eclipse JS validator not JSHint plugin are run in a build despite being installed.